# MS Bot framework error 'Activity' namespace not found

Tags: c#, .net, bots

I'm using Visual Studio Mac (Beta) to try and get the sample Microsoft Bot framework to run.  I've tried to follow all the installation instructions but when running it I get an error saying the type or namespace name 'Activity' cannot be found.

Example usage of it is:-
public async Task Post([FromBody]Activity activity)

The inline help suggests I need the System.EnterpriseServices using directive but when I add this I get additional errors so I'm guessing it's not this.

I've not changed the code at all from that downloaded at https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html - so I'm unclear what this might be.

I'm guessing this is related, but under 'References' the System.Web.Entity is greyed out with a message saying 'Assembly not found for framework .net framework 4.6'.  I've looked online and I can't see how to resolve this error or download this assembly.

It's been many years so I last coded (and that was Delphi) so it could just be how I've set things up to play with it - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a NuGet reference to [`Microsoft.Bot.Builder`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/)? I think you might need to add that, after which the `Activity` class can be referenced correctly.